# Watson speech to text authentication

Tags: authentication, browser, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-iam

I am trying to get [Transcribe from Microphone](https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/microphone-streaming.html) working on my server as a starting point.

The code is straightforward but I am having trouble with the token.

on IBMcloud I created a IAM-Service id with Access Policies
Viewer, Reader  14  Speech to Text service in all resource groups

created an apikey from that

created the token file

```
    curl -k -X POST  --output token \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \
  --data-urlencode "apikey={apikey}" \
  "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
```

the response has 'access_token' but the javascript SDK 0.38.1 looks for 'accessToken'

when I start microphone I get a socket error 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"

I checked token expiration.

I confirmed it is an auth problem:

```
 curl -X GET "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/models?access_token="{accessToken}"
```

responds "unauthorized"

I have researched and am unsure what to do next.  My best guess is I am generating the token improperly.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the token generation to the code. All the SDKs have an [IAMAuthenticator component](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#authentication). The full [documentation for Node.js is here](https://github.com/IBM/node-sdk-core/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md). It has a very simple example where you pass in the API key:

```
import { IamAuthenticator } from 'ibm-cloud-sdk-core';

const authenticator = new IamAuthenticator({
  apikey: '{apikey}',
});
```

Thereafter, you instantiate the service, e.g., STT.